# python request.get API arguments, headers, parameters - confusion

Tags: python, filter, parameters, request, arguments

For Python request to an API, I'm confused about URL parameters, arguments and request.get() parameters, even after reading both Python and API documentation. I want to get only the dog with 'name': 'Akita'.

Following code works for the limit of 5 records but which ones returned are random, not just the 'Akita' (which I know exists). I've tried many permutations of quotes, braces, format of dictionary, pre-writing strings, etc. All return either no records, all the records or syntax fail.

```
response_dog = requests.get("https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=5", params={'name': 'Akita'})
for current_dog in response_dog.json():
    print("\n",current_dog)
```

output is 5 random dogs; desired is just the one dog of 'name': 'Akita'

Answer (score 0):

If you want information for a specific dog breed, why are you using the API endpoint that yields information for random dogs?

I think what you're looking for is:
https://docs.thedogapi.com/api-reference/breeds/breeds-search#send-a-test-request

The documentation tells you how to formulate your request, including headers, query-string parameters, and endpoint URL:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search"

params = {
    "q": "akita"
}

headers = {
    "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY"
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()

print(response.json()[0]["temperament"])
```

Note: I haven't tested this since I don't have an API key, but according to the documentation it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that there are different options after the /v1.

Comment: But what I still don't get is how the site knew that {"q":"Akita"} was providing "Akita" as search string for the name field, not the origin field or country code field. There seems to be a dozen fields on this page: https://docs.thedogapi.com/api-reference/breeds/breeds-search . But none of them are 'q'.  What if I wanted to search for the value '65 - 115' within the 'imperial' key within the 'weight' key? thanks.

Comment: @PlayingwithGAS I think you may be misinterpreting the documentation. What the documentation refers to as "Schema" (id, name, temperament, life_span, etc.) is what is contained in the response from the server. The schema defines the keys of the key-value pairs you can expect to see in the response JSON. You do not use these keys to formulate your request - they are only relevant for the response. The only reason that I knew to use the query-string parameter `q` is because the documentation told me to use it: `q [string] - Part of the name of the breed to search for`.

Comment: This specific API endpoint happens to accept only one query-string parameter, `q`, which you can use to search for breeds. You can't use this query-string parameter with this endpoint to search by weight or height, for example.

Comment: To drive the point home: If I make a request to this endpoint with `q=poodle`, then the JSON response contains a list of four dictionaries, where each of the four `name` keys (from the schema) map to the following distinct values: `Poodle`, `Poodle (Miniature)`, `Poodle (Toy)` and `Toy Poodle`. Don't confuse the `name` key from the schema with the `q` query-string parameter. `q` is just a substring of the breed (or the entire name of a breed) that you're looking for. The response contains all breeds that fit your search criteria.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that. Completely clear now.      I was, as you observed, confusing the response json schema with the request. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help if you have further questions.